# which event gets triggered upon installation of the windows8 app? I want to create indexdb database on installation of the app

Tags: javascript, html, windows-8

I was just wondering where and how I should be creating indexdb database in my win8 app. I am not sure which event gets triggered when the app is first installed on user machine.

I believe that 
 if (args.detail.kind === activation.ActivationKind.launch)
is for checking and performing things when the app gets launched everytime, what I am looking for is the first time.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "on installed" behavior. You should detect your first run (by saving off a value in local settings or similar), and do you database creation then.

e.g. in your activation handler write code like:

```
if(!window.localSettings["createdDb"]) {
    createDB();
    window.localSettings["createdDb"] = true;
}
```

Comment: yap, well thats a way to go for sure. Thanks for the reply I guess I will do the same.